# LateInitializationError: Field 'TaakBeschrijving' has not been initialized

Tags: firebase, flutter

by runtime everything works fine but when I press on the button to send the data to the database firebase Firestore I get this error
`

1. this is my error
   [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'TaakBeschrijving' has not been initialized.
   #0      _TaakState.TaakBeschrijving (package:cameratest2/Taak.dart)
   #1      _TaakState.uploadText (package:cameratest2/Taak.dart:72:50)
   #2      _TaakState.afrondenbutton. (package:cameratest2/Taak.dart:333:13)
   #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
   #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
   #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
   #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
   #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
   `

```
2. this is my code
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:cameratest2/Homedashboard.dart';
import 'package:cameratest2/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:multi_image_picker2/multi_image_picker2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;
// import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';


class Taak extends StatefulWidget{

  _TaakState createState() => _TaakState();

}

class _TaakState extends State<Taak> {

  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage ref =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

 // //  late String filePath = uploadFile(filePath) as String;
 //  // String filePath = "IMG_7337.HEIC";
 //  String? downloadURL;
 //
 //    Future uploadfoto() async {
 //      try {
 //         Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("gs://cameratest2-41782.appspot.com");
 //            await ref.putFile(image!);
 //            downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
 //            print(downloadURL);
 //            //then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
 //        } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
 //          e.code == 'wat miss gegaan';
 //        }

    //     await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("fotos")".putFile(fileToUpload)";
    //         // .then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
    //     } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    //       e.code == 'wat miss gegaan';
    //     }
    // // File file = File(filePath);
    // // assert(file.absolute.existsSync());
    //
    //   firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("fotos").putFile(image!);
    //     // .then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));
    //
    //   // uploadFile(filePath).then((value) => print({('het is je gelukt')}));

   String? downloadURL;
  
// methode for sending Pictures to to the data base 
   Future<void> uploadPhoto() async {
     firebase_storage.Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images");
     await ref.putFile(image!);
     downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
     print(downloadURL);
   }

  late final String TaakBeschrijving;
  late final String TaakOplossing;

  // text string mothde to send text data to the database 
  Future<void> uploadText() async {
    String dataUrl = 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==';

    try {
      await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('uploads/hello-world.text').child(TaakBeschrijving!).child(TaakOplossing!)
          .putString(dataUrl, format: firebase_storage.PutStringFormat.dataUrl);
    } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Taak'),),
        body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
            value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
            child: GestureDetector(
                child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              colors: [
                                Color(0x66012e67),
                                Color(0x99012e67),
                                Color(0xcc012e67),
                                Color(0xff012e67),
                              ]

                          )),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25,
                          vertical: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: 1,),
                            afrondenbutton(),
                            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                            taakbeschrijving(),
                            SizedBox(height: 30,),
                            taakoplossing(),
                            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                            bewijsmatriaal(),
                            SizedBox(height: 20,),
                            uploadbutton(context),
                            SizedBox(height: 50, width: 100,),
                            screen(context),
                            SizedBox(height: 200, width: 100,),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(

                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: buildGridViewimages(
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                          // Text('',
                          //   style: TextStyle(
                          //     color: Colors.white,
                          //     fontSize: 40,
                          //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                          // ),),


                          // ],
                        ),
                        // ),
                        // );

                      ),
                    ),
                    ])))

    );
  }


  // Future<void> loadAssets() async {
  //   List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];
  //   String error = 'No Error Detected';

  //   resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
  //     maxImages: 10,
  //     materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
  //       actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
  //       actionBarTitle: "Example App",
  //       allViewTitle: "All Photos",
  //       useDetailsView: false,
  //       selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
  //     ),
  //   );
  //
  //   setState(() =>
  //   {
  //     this.images = resultList as File?;
  //     error = error;
  //   });z
  // }
  //
  // File? image, images;
  //
  // Future<void> pickImage() async {
  //   final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  //   if (image == null) return;
  //   if (image.path == null) return;
  //
  //   final imageFile = File(image.path);
  //   setState(() => this.image = imageFile);
  //
  // }
  //
  // Future getCamera() async {
  //   final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
  //       source: ImageSource.camera);
  //
  //   setState(() {
  //     if (pickedFile != null) {
  //       image = File(pickedFile.path);
  //     }
  //   });
  // }

//   Future<void> loadAssets() async {
//   List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];
//   String error = 'No Error Detected';
//
//   resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
//     maxImages: 10,
//     materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
//       actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
//       actionBarTitle: "Example App",
//       allViewTitle: "All Photos",
//       useDetailsView: false,
//       selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
//     ),
//   );
//
//   setState(() => {
//
//     this.images = resultList
//   }
//
//   );
// }

  File? image;
  List<Asset> images = <Asset>[];

  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
// late List<File> images;

// <vooi>
  Future pickImage() async {
    final pick = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if (pick != null) {
        image = File(pick.path);
      }
      else {
        print(Error);
      }
    });

    // final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    // if (image == null) return;
    // if (image.path == null) return;

    // final imageFile = File(image.path);
    // this.image = imageFile;
    // setState(() => this.image = imageFile);
  }

  Future getCamera() async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        image = File(pickedFile.path);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> loadAssets() async {
    List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];

    resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
      maxImages: 20,
      enableCamera: true,
      selectedAssets: images,
      cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
      materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
        actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
        actionBarTitle: "Example App",
        allViewTitle: "All Photos",
        useDetailsView: false,
        selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      // uploadFile(filePath);
      images = resultList;
    });
  }

  Widget buildGridViewimages() {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        Asset asset = images[index];
        return AssetThumb(
          asset: asset,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget screen(BuildContext context) {
    if (image != null) {
      return
        Image.file(image!);
    } else {
      loadAssets();
      return FlutterLogo();
    }
  }

  // final Winkel store = Winkel();


  Widget afrondenbutton() {
    final ButtonStyle raisedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      onPrimary: Colors.white,
      primary: Colors.green[300],
      minimumSize: Size(260, 36),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
      ),
    );
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Afronden'),
        style: raisedButtonStyle,
        onPressed: () {
          // if(image != null) {
            uploadText();
          }

          // .store.uploadFile(filePath).then((value) => print('het is je gelukt'));
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget uploadbutton(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle raisedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      onPrimary: Colors.white,
      primary: Colors.green[300],
      minimumSize: Size(180, 36),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
      ),
    );
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Uploaden'),
          style: raisedButtonStyle,
          // FlutterLogo();
          onPressed: () {
            showImageSourceActionSheet(context);

            // Image.network(
            //   'https://i0.wp.com/www.joyfromjoyce.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/shutterstock_642124366.jpg?fit=1000%2C667&ssl=1',
            //   width: 100, height: 50,);
            // //       // Image.file(File(imagePath)

          }

      ),

    );
  }
```

`im trying to send data String and pictures to firebase database storage but im getting error with late initialization and null check what is going on so with both ways im getting error is there any other way to solve this please can any one help?`

Comment: a simple trick will be making it nullable  `String? TaakBeschrijving` and check null when using it. and while the method is `future` use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh both ways don't works String? and late final I tried both that's way im confused

Comment: Hope below answer will solve the issue, I just read the code-text :D

Comment: @yeasinSheikh thnx the answer below helped me fix the error empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the `late` in this variable declaration:

```
late final String TaakBeschrijving;
```

By using `late` here you're saying: "I don't know the value of this variable now, but I promise to give it a value before I ever read from it". Then your code goes ahead and reads `TaakBeschrijving` before it has gotten a value, so Flutter tells you that you broke your promise.

---

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Initialize `TaakBeschrijving` before using it, as you promised by using `late`
2. Make `TaakBeschrijving` nullable (as Yeasin also commented):

   ```
   String? TaakBeschrijving;
   ```

   So now you're telling Flutter that `TaakBeschrijving` may either be a string or it may be null, and Flutter will help you deal with the possible null in all of your code.
3. Give `TaakBeschrijving` an initial value:

   ```
   var TaakBeschrijving = "default value";
   ```

   Now if you read `TaakBeschrijving` before changing its value, it'll have its default value.

Which of these solutions is best depends on your situation.

Comment: i will try this one the var TaakBeschrijving = "default value";

Comment: thanks a lot this solution Empty String helped me fix the problem I will also try it with photos